# How do I properly handle multiple VirtualHosts on one server with only one having SSL?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, virtualhost

I have the following apache2 VirtualHost config:

```
<VirtualHost {my_server_ip}:443>
 ServerName securesite.com
 ServerAlias www.securesite.com
 DocumentRoot /data/web/securesite.com/
 Options -Indexes
 SSLEngine On
 SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/securesite.com/securesite.com.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/securesite.com/server.key
 SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/securesite.com/gd_bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /data/web/unsecuresite.com/
 ServerName unsecuresite.com
 ServerAlias www.unsecuresite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that I can access `https://unsecuresite.com/` and the server returns the data for `securesite.com` and the browser complains.

Why does this happen? Why does ServerName for 443 matches other server names?

Can I somehow handle this? Maybe catch the request, handle it with regex and redirect it to its proper place?

**EDIT**

`ports.conf` says:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    NameVirtualHost {my_server_ip}:443
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you  have `NameVirtualHost` earlier in your config?

Comment: @Joe: edited to include the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the following method:

```
<VirtualHost {my_server_ip}:443>
 ServerName securesite.com
 ServerAlias www.securesite.com
 DocumentRoot /data/web/securesite.com/
 Options -Indexes
 SSLEngine On
 SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/securesite.com/securesite.com.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/securesite.com/server.key
 SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/securesite.com/gd_bundle.crt
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?(securesite\.com){1}$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you connect to `https://securesite.com/`, then you are actually connecting to port 443. Since there is only one site listening on port 443, the first match is returned (even though the ServerName does not match.

Your configuration basically boils down to:

```
<VirtualHost {my_server_ip}:443>
 ServerName securesite.com
 # ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName unsecuresite.com
 # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

This means that any request to port 80 (`http`) will be served by `unsecuresite.com` and requests to port 443 (`https`) are served by `securesite.com`.

Even if you add a `<VirtualHost *:443> ServerName unsecuresite.com`, you can still not simply trick the user to redirect without having a valid certificate for `unsecuresite.com`. (That would result in a ugly certificate warning.)

If your `unsecuresite.com` vhost is not supposed to handle HTTPS, then just ignore it. With nginx you could reset a connection if the hostname does not match, I don't know if something similar exists for Apache.

Comment: I would ignore it, but for some strange reason, Google indexed ``https://unsecuresite.com`` and the Google search data returns the content of the secure site. I mean, seriously, I don't get why they would even TRY crawling that location.

Comment: @RichardRodriguez Since you have only one canonical host (`https://www.example.com/` instead of `http://www.example.com/` or even `http://example.com`), what about redirecting if `%{HTTP_HOST}` does not match the server name?

Comment: I wanted to redirect, yes, but as you said yourself, "That would result in a ugly certificate warning."

Comment: @RichardRodriguez For "normal" clients, yes. Apparently Google's crawler does not care about the validity of the certificate or the certificate is still valid for your other domain.

Comment: So how do I redirect it? Should I somehow do it as a default 443 vhost with some HOST condition? I have no idea how to do this, tbh :(

Comment: @RichardRodriguez You have two possibilities: Use `RewriteCond` to restrict a redirect in the vhost for `securesite.com:443` *or* create a new vhost before the other ones and add a `Redirect / http://unsecuresite.com/` to that new vhost. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost